# Broadcast-receiver must not start new Activity if my Application is Shown?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have `BroadcastReceiver` when new `Message` is received will start `MessageActivity`, but how not to start this `Activity` if my `MainActivity` is in front of screen?

By the way, I am trying to not use `Singleton Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep track of your Activity with OnResume and onPause methods.
So something like this should help you to check if MainActivity is on foreground.

```
private boolean isForeground;

public void onResume() {
    isForeground = true;
}

public void onPause() {
    isForeground = false;
}
```

Comment: How you can get instance of `MainActivity`, so you can access none static methods you mentioned ?